# What the equivalent of OFFSET in Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got a result set of 100 rows using Spark SQL. I want to get final result starting from row number 6 to 15. In SQL we use `OFFSET` to skip rows like `OFFSET 5 LIMIT 10` is used to get rows from number 6 to 15. In Spark SQL, How can I achieve the same?

Comment: You can type raw SQL into Spark SQL, so what isn't working for you?

Comment: `(SELECT name, address FROM table WHERE city = 'Dallas')
UNION
(SELECT name, address FROM table WHERE city ='Phoenix') OFFSET 5 LIMIT 10` . I am getting `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input 'OFFSET' expecting {<EOF>, ',', '.', '[', 'LIMIT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'WINDOW', EQ, '<=>', '<>', '!=', '<', LTE, '>', GTE, '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', 'DIV', '&', '|', '^', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE'}(line 1, pos 407)` Probably I am missing something.

Comment: Does `OFFSET` work in Spark SQL?

Comment: The error seems to suggest it does not. This was asked yesterday, by the way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42560815/in-pyspark-hivecontext-what-is-the-equivalent-of-sql-offset

Comment: And here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260134/skip-take-with-spark-sql

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Welcome... always search for your questions before posting

Answer (score 3):

I guess SparkSQL does not support *offset*. So I use *id* as the filter condition. Each time, I only retrieve *N* data.

The following is my sample code:

```
sc = SparkContext()  
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
        .options(header='false', inferschema='true')\
        .load('your.csv')
sqlContext.registerDataFrameAsTable(df, "table")

batch_size = 10 ** 5
res = sqlContext.sql("select min(C0), max(C0) from table).collect()
index = int(res[0]._c0) - 1
N_max = int(res[0]._c1)
while index < N_max:
    prev = index
    sql = "select C0, C1, C2, C3 from table \
            where C0 > '%s' and C0 <= '%s' \
            order by C0 limit %d" % (index, index+batch_size, batch_size)
    res = sqlContext.sql(sql).collect()
    # do something ...

    if index < prev + batch_size:
        index = prev + batch_size
```