# how to implement offset in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

Spark-sql does not have support for offset only supports limit. My query returns a huge result and to get the specific  rows  I wrote spark sql as follows

```
select col1, col2 from (
select d.Diagnosis_Start_Date as col1, 
e.Encounter_ID as col2, 
row_number() over (order by d.Patient_ID) as row_num 
from Diagnoses d, Encounters e 
where d.Patient_ID = e.Patient_ID) 
where row_num between 300 and 310;
```

But this is giving

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3.0 (TID 249, ip-172-31-9-85.us-west-1.compute.internal, executor 23): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 23 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Container killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. 6.2 GB of 5.5 GB physical memory used. Consider boosting spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1505)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1492)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1675)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1664)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkConte
```

Comment: what is the result you are expecting.. you said specif row... can you add that condition in WHERE clause

Comment: Well getting it through where clause always was not possible and that is why exploring other options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What the equivalent of OFFSET in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591763/what-the-equivalent-of-offset-in-spark-sql)