# Is there an "offset" to go with "limit" for Databricks SQL to enable paging

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I'm seeing documentation for "limit" for Databricks/Apache Spark SQL (e.g. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-limit.html), but I'm not seeing how to do an offset to enable paging?  Is there a way to do an offset and a limit to get the second 100 rows back from a query.

Something like this does not work? What would?

```
%sql
select * from enc
limit 100
offset 100
;
```

This does work, but now I would like to get the second 100 rows, how do I do the offset?

```
%sql
select * from enc
limit 100
;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What the equivalent of OFFSET in Spark SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591763/what-the-equivalent-of-offset-in-spark-sql)

Comment: I'm not understanding how the expression translates into a sql string that would do the offset.  It looks like the %d is replace by what is in the following "% (index, index+batch_size, batch_size)".  But that would only do the limit and not the offset.  Wouldn't the generated query still bring back the entire data set for the last page? This does not work: "%sql select * from enc limit(100,100,100)"

Comment: The error message is this: The limit expression must be integer type, but got struct<col1:int,col2:int,col3:int>;;